# Google sheets - Conditional formatting row based on cell contents where contents is a date/time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet containing a date and time (eg. 02/07/2016 15:06:00) in column B.

I am wanting to highlight rows based on the 'hour' portion of the cell - typically anything between 12:00 and 12:59 to be highlight in one colour and anything else to be highlighted in another colour.

I have the following code which is working as expected, however it is based on a string value not a date value:

```
function Formatting1() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var columnO = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1);
  var oValues = columnO.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < oValues.length; i++) {
    if (oValues[i][0] == 'No call received') {
      sheet.getRange(i + 2, 1, 1, 6 ).setBackgroundColor('#FF3300');
    }
  }
}
```

It's the handling of the date/time range that has me stumped!  Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using conditional formatting and the formula rule `=HOUR(D2) = 12` applied to `B2:B`.

If you want to use the function you just need to change the if statement to

```
if (oValues[i][0].getHours() === 12)
```

Assuming the first column of `oValues` contains the date.
Google Apps Script reads Spreadsheet dates as [Javascript dates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours).

Be careful about timezones though, the timezone of a spreadsheet can be different from the time zone the script operates in so the conditional formatting option has less potential for headaches.

Comment: Genius!  Thank you so much!